# Jquery/Ajax/CSS show/hide div after form subimit with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, jinja2

I am having an issue showing a hidden DIV after posting a form with Ajax. The setup is like so;

index.html - My content and form is loaded into a div from a resource page

```
<div id="inst_stud_resource_change_success" style="display: none;">
            <div class="greenbox">
            Deleted!
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="inst_stud_resources_getpackages">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $("#inst_stud_resources_getpackages").fadeOut("slow").load('/inst/stud/resources/getpackages?inst_id={{ inst.id }}&stud_id={{ stud.id }}').fadeIn('slow');
            </script>
        </div>
```

/inst/stud/resources/getpackages.html - this page has the form, and the content needed for the DIV on index.html

The Jquery is used like so on getpackages.html;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#delete_package').on('submit', function(event) {

    $.ajax({
        data : {
            stud_id : $('#stud_id').val(),
            pck_id : $('#pck_id').val()
        },
        type : 'POST',
        url : '{{ url_for('mod_inst_stud.delete_package2') }}'
    })
    .done(function(data) {

        if (data.error) {
            $('#errorAlert').text(data.error).show(); // IGNORE haven't gotten this far
            $('#successAlert').hide(); // IGNORE haven't gotten this far
        }
        else {
            $("#inst_stud_resources_getpackages").hide(); // doesn't seem to do anything
            $('#inst_stud_resource_change_success').show(); // never shows the div on Index.html
            $('#inst_stud_resource_change_success').delay(3200).hide(); // never hides, since it is never shown..
            $("#inst_stud_resources_getpackages").load('/inst/stud/resources/getpackages?inst_id={{ inst.id }}&stud_id={{ stud.id }}').show(); // this seems to work since the div from index.html is updated with the new content from getpackages.html
        }

    });

    event.preventDefault();

});
```

});

Any ideas what is going on? I'm not really that verse in web development, my background is more in python/flask, not Jquery/Ajax/CSS.

Comment: This is pretty unclear bud `I am having an issue showing a hidden DIV after posting a form with Ajax`, you need to say what you are having right now and what you've done so far

Comment: Are you sure that your event handler is binding to `#delete_package`? I don't know where `#delete_package` is in your HTML, but if it's a child of `#inst_stud_resources_getpackages` then your event handler wouldn't bind at all. I would recommend putting a breakpoint in your code using your browser's developer tools. That way you can see exactly what code is being reached and what is not. E.g., https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/

Comment: Well, what happens is.. after the form submit, I return some JSON to the Ajax to find out if it successfully submitted or failed, if successful I want to show a DIV for 5 seconds saying it was successful. Currently the code I have above is not showing the DIV at all when it returns successful. All it does is reload the content, but I want that to come last after showing the successful DIV.

Comment: Yes, I know #delete_package is binded, because the last line of the else statement works. It reloads the new content into the DIV. But it seems the 3 lines before it do nothing. I'm not sure why..

Comment: Im thinking the ajax returns error. The last line in the else statement doesnt execute. Instead the doc is loaded by this script  $("#inst_stud_resources_getpackages").fadeOut("slow").load('/inst/stud/resources/getpackages?inst_id={{ inst.id }}&stud_id={{ stud.id }}').fadeIn('slow');

Comment: I wish that were the case.. I know it is returning successful because the script on the server end does what I expect it to do, delete the package from the database. Than it sends back a JSON response, and it should execute the 4 lines under the else statement, but it seems only the last line gets executed. Again i know it gets executed because it shows the new content (i.e the package that was deleted is no longer there)

Comment: Okay what data does it return?

Comment: The url property on your Ajax call is not escaping single-quotes `'` - do you see any errors in your browser console?

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution..

```
else {
            $("#inst_stud_resources_getpackages").hide();
            $('#inst_stud_resource_change_success').fadeIn(1000);
            $('#inst_stud_resource_change_success').delay(2600).fadeOut(3500);
            $("#inst_stud_resources_getpackages").delay(7200).fadeIn().load('/inst/stud/resources/getpackages?inst_id={{ inst.id }}&stud_id={{ stud.id }}');
        }
```

Apparently there is a queue in Jquery, however .load() will always go to the front. So It was negating the order of my calls. I had to move some lines around, and add an animation to .load() in order to delay it from loading right way. Seems to be working well now.